# GROUP BY WITH CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a table with group by like this:

[image: table 1]

and i want to have a result like this

[image: table 2]

i compare the state, if i have one up state so the result will up

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include text rather than images next time.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name,MAX(state)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

Because state is a varchar (assumption), the maximum is an alphabetical order, favouring 'up'.

If its an enum, it still will work if 'up' is the second element of the enum.

Comment: *If its an enum, it still will work if 'up' is the second element of the enum.* If 'up' is more letter then 'down', more precisely, else use MIN().

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=49655060a600d727b3474faeb9adc922)**

```
select 
  name,
  case
   when max(state = 'up') then 'up'
   else 'down'
  end state
 from 
 mytable
 group by name;
```

result:

```
name | state
PLR  | up
VRL  | down
```

Comment: `case` statement for `if`/`else` conditions sometimes get a bit verbose `IF(max(state='up'),'up', 'down') state` is sufficient. A true expression `state='up'` is 1 else 0 already. `= 1` redundant as `0=1` is false and `1=1` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below query:

```
select A.name, (case when A.up_state>0 then 'up' else 'down' end) as state
from (
 select name, sum(case when state='up' then 1 else 0 end) as up_state 
 from table_name
 group by name
) as A
```